# Override CSS in an encoded PHP Include

Tags: php, css, include

I bought a script that is ioncube encoded.  It's a file on my site that is called from a php include, but the text is HUGE, like 38px. Completely unacceptable.  The vendor says there's no way to reduce this font size, it's coming from from CSS in the encoded file.  Is there some kind of code I can wrap around the php include to override the style settings?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have a demo url or maybe you can show the css?

Comment: have to try to override the styling in your own css using the **!important**

Answer (score 0):

There can be at least two ways:

- on-the-fly replace of rule your want to change manyaly (`preg_replace`, for example)
- just after the place you insert your CSS insert your own  block with

  `.your-element-class {
    font-size: 24px !important; 
  }` inside it